# Are newer `btrfs-progs` versions safe to use with older kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, btrfs

For example btrfs-progs-4.17 on kernel 4.14 - any issues, or can just upgrade btrfs-progs with no "back-compatibility" concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the actively maintained [btrfs Wiki on kernel.org](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_version_of_btrfs-progs_should_I_use_for_my_kernel.3F)...

---

> ***What version of btrfs-progs should I use for my kernel?***
>
> Simply use the latest version.
>
> The userspace tools versions roughly match the kernel releases and
> should contain support for features introduced in the respective
> kernel release. The minor versions are bugfix releases or independent
> updates (eg. documentation, tests).

---

> ***Do I have to keep my btrfs-progs at the same version as my kernel?***
>
> No.
>
> If your btrfs-progs is newer than your kernel, then you may not be
> able to use some of the features that the btrfs-progs offers, because
> the kernel doesn't support them.
>
> If your btrfs-progs is older than your kernel, then you may not be
> able to use some of the features that the kernel offers, because the
> btrfs-progs doesn't support them.
>
> Other than that, there should be no restrictions on which versions
> work together.

---

Comment: (y) not sure why I didn't think to check their wiki.